# Firebase call does not update value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a problem on updating a value in firebase.
Here is the scenario and code:
I'm running a forEach loop on some data, about 300 records.  I update state locally and in the callback I have a function that executes this code (partial).

```
.then(memKey => {
  this.setState({
    memberKeyID: memKey,
    family: {[memKey]: [first, last, 'Head of house']},
    memberSaved: true,
    readOnly: true
  }, () => {
    this.props.firebase.getMemberCount(currentOrganization).once('value')
                      .then(count => {
                        console.log(count.val());
                        if(count.val()) {
                          const countTotal = count.val() + 1;
                          return countTotal;
                        } else {
                          return 1;
                        }
                      })
                      .then(memberCount => {
                        console.log(memberCount);
                        this.props.firebase.setMemberCount(currentOrganization, memberCount)
                      })
  })
})
```

I make a call to `getMemberCount` which at the time returns 5
when we console.log(count.val()) I get '5'.  So going off this I would expect when I call the next then and pass memberCount that I would set an updated value.
In example:
First time it runs countTotal = 5 + 1; should return 6
then next time countTotal = 6 + 1 etc.
However that is not the case.  I'm getting 5 for the amount of records we loop.
When data has 300 records I get '5' console logged 300 times.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the call to `setMemberCount` is going to be asynchronous and will complete some time later, probably after the loop completes.  The updated value won't be seen immediately by the next iteration of the loop that calls `getMemberCount`.  If you want to see the updated data, you should wait until the promise resolves from whatever code inside `setMemberCount` actually performs the update.  Otherwise, if you don't wait for that promise, the database is not fully updated.